# Axios nested request function return

Tags: reactjs, promise, async-await, httprequest, axios

I'm trying to get a image data from an API and. To do that I first need to get it's ID and then use it to get the image. To maintain a clean code, I'm using a function to do that, I'm having problems when I try to return the response to the component I call the function.

**getNextImageData**

```
export const getNextImageData = () => {
  const apiToken = lscache.get('apiToken')
  return(
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://myapiurl/images/',
      params: {
        limit: '1',
        doc_cat: ''
      },
      responseType: 'json'
    })
      .then(response => {
        lscache.set('imageData', response, 30)
        axios({
          method: 'get',
          url: 'https://myapiurl/images/' + response.data[0].id + '/',
        })
          .then(response => {
            return(response.data)
          })
      })
  )
}
```

**MyClass**

```
class MyClass extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      image: undefined
    }
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    const data = await getNextImageData()
    this.setState({
      image: data,
    })
  }
  render() {
  // something
  }
}
```

I receive nothing from the return, when I pasted the code directly into my component, it worked fine, but I want to use it inside a function

Comment: your getNextImageData function is not returning the promise you are trying to await from axios.. try to add return statement before:    return axios({method:'get' ....

Comment: @jure unfortunately, I already tried it, I removed it because I thought that it was interfering in the function return. But since it can cause confusion, Ill edit my question, thanks

Comment: This way it won't work. Instead return a `promise` from `getNextImageData()` and then resolve that promise into your component.

Comment: @TheCoder I can resolve the last `promise` in my component, ok. But I have two nested promises, how would I do that? Resolve two nested requests in the component? Dividing those two axios calls in two different functions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was nesting it wrongly, you don't use a `then` inside another `then`, you use them on the same level. And every axios call follows a `return` statement. Doing so I didn't even need to use async/await, I used another `promise`.

**getNextImageData**

```
export const getNextImageData = () => {
  const apiToken = lscache.get('apiToken')
  return axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://myapiurl/images/',
    params: {
      limit: '1',
      doc_cat: ''
    },
    responseType: 'json'
  })
    .then(response => {
      lscache.set('imageData', response, 30)
      return axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'https://myapiurl/images/' + response.data[0].id + '/',
      })
    })
    .then(response => {
      return response.data
    })
}
```

**MyClass**

```
class MyClass extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      image: undefined
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    getNextImageData()
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({
        image: data,
      })
    })
  }
  render() {
  // something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
export const getNextImageData = async () => {
  const apiToken = lscache.get('apiToken')
   const data = await axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://myapiurl/images/',
      params: {
        limit: '1',
        doc_cat: ''
      },
      responseType: 'json'
    });
const firstResponse = await data; //
// set local storage 
lscache.set('imageData', firstResponse, 30)
const second = await axios({
          method: 'get',
          url: 'https://myapiurl/images/' + firstResponse.data[0].id + '/',
        });
const thirdResponse = await second.data;
return thirdResponse;
}
```

Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the state once you have all the data ready.

so you set state inside the last axios call.

You could also do it with a callbackHandler or somethig similar to keep your code clean.

```
class MyClass extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      image: undefined
    }
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    const nextImageResponse = await getNextImageData()
    // If your first response is success make the next call
    if( nextImageResponse.hasOwnProperty('data') ){
      lscache.set('imageData', response, 30)
        axios({
          method: 'get',
          url: 'https://myapiurl/images/' + nextImageResponse.data[0].id + '/',
        })
          .then(response => {
            if( response.hasOwnProperty('data'){
              this.setState({ image: response.data, nextImage: nextImageResponse.data });       
            }
        })
    }
  }
  render() {
  // something
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But as I said, if I use my code directly in the component, it work as well. What I want to do is to use a function call to make the code as clean as possible, using the axios logic outside the component code